# signup form isn't working while login is working fine on django

Tags: python, django

I cant do sigup while Login is working fine

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['first_name', 'last_name',
                'email', 'username',
                'password']
        label={
            'password':'Password'

}
def clean_email(self):
    if self.cleaned_data['email'].endswith('@gmail.com')
    return self.cleaned_data['email']
    else:
        raise ValidationError("error")

def save(self):
    password=self.cleaned_data.pop('password')
    u=super().save()
    u.set_password(password)
    u.save()
    return u
```

Link to project- https://github.com/tsuryaa/my_project/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't use the phrase "It doesnt/isnt working" It is a useless phrase and means nothing. What isnt working? What did you expect to happen that isnt? What is happening instead?  http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: What do you want ? Wath happen in your project ?

Comment: Please provide exact and specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your indentation.  At present the `save` and `clean` methods are not part of the UserForm class.  It should look more like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['first_name', 'last_name',
                'email', 'username',
                'password']
        label={
            'password':'Password'
            }
    def save(self):
        password=self.cleaned_data.pop('password')
        u=super().save()
        u.set_password(password)
        u.save()
        return u
```

The whole `clean` method should be indentent also, so it is part of `UserForm` and not at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement in your `clean_mail` method is missing a colon.

```
def clean_email(self):
    if self.cleaned_data['email'].endswith('@gmail.com'):
        ...
```

Also in your `save` method you have to have the argument `commit`.If anything overrides your form, or wants to modify what it's saving, it will do `save(commit=False)`, modify the output, and then save it itself.

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    password = self.cleaned_data.pop('password')
    u = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
    # do custom stuff here
    u.set_password(password)
    if commit:
        u.save()
    return u
```

You can read more about the `save method` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Comment: i commented the whole clean_email still the same, instead of adding user and giving success message it remains on the same page.

Comment: Indent the whole clean and save methods.  They are not part of the ModelForm class, they need to be indented.